# Algebraic characterization of a union of two affine subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it a simple algebraic characterization of affine hull of the union of an affine set $A$ in a linear space and a point $x$ not lying in this hyperspace?

I thought that it is $$\{(1-t)a+tx: t\in \mathbb R, a\in A\}$$
but it is not true.

For example in $\mathbb R^2$ for $A=\{(x,0): x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $x=(0,1)$:

$Aff(A\cup \{x\})$ should be $\mathbb R^2$ but it is different from $\{(1-t)a+tx: t\in \mathbb R, a\in A\}$
(points of the form $(1,y)$, $y\in \mathbb R$ are not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

#### The expression is wrong. It should be

$Aff(A\cup\{x\}) = \{\sum_{i=0}^{m} \lambda_ia_i+ (1-\sum_{i=0}^m\lambda_i)x: \forall a_i \in A,\}$.

#### Let us deduce that step by step.

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let us denote $dim(A) = m$.

$(dim(A) = m) \Longrightarrow (\exists   \{a_0,\dots,a_m\}, dim\{a_0,\dots,a_m\} = m)$,    where $\{a_0,\dots,a_m\}$ is a set of independent points in affine space $A$.
In fact, the linear subspace parallel to $A$ is $L = Aff \{0,a_1-a_0,\dots,a_m-a_0\}$.
Therefore, $A = L + a_0$.  $A = \bigcup\sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i(a_i-a_0)+ a_0=\bigcup\sum_{i=0}^{m} \lambda_ia_i$, where $\sum_{i=0}^{m}\lambda_i = 1$.

suppose there is another point $a'\notin A$.
Then $a'$ is independent of points $\{a_0, \dots,a_m\}$.
$Aff(A\cup\{x\}) = Aff(\{a_0, \dots, a_m,a'\}) = L'+a'$, where $L' = Aff\{0, a_0-a',\dots,a_m-a'\}$. Note also that $dim(L') = m+1$. Then we can express
$Aff(A\cup\{x\}) = \bigcup\sum_{i=0}^{m} \lambda_i(a_i-a') + a'=\bigcup\sum_{i=0}^{m} \lambda_ia_i+ (1-\sum_{i=0}^m\lambda_i)a'$. For ease of notation, let $\lambda' = 1-\sum_{i=0}^m\lambda_i.$

#### Check the results with your example

In your example, $a' = (0,1), a_0= (0,0), a_1 = (1,0)$,  $A = L$ is points in x-axis.
$L' is$ x-y plane. $A'$ is also x-y plane. To generate points in $(1,y)$, $\lambda_1 =1, \lambda'= y, \lambda_0 = -y.$

#### Any questions ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @guanglei In $\mathbb R^2$ for $A=\{(x,0): x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $x=(0,1)$:

$Aff(A\cup \{x\})$ should be $\mathbb R^2$ but it is different from $\{(1-t)a+tx: t\in \mathbb R, a\in A\}$  
(points of the form $(1,y)$, $y\in \mathbb R$ are not).

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you very much. I can revised the answer.

Comment: @user172903 You are right. I give  another answer.